How to change preset while playing?
I encountered some issues regarding changing the preset of a soundfont (sf2) file:
I found that calling sendProgramChange does not change the soundfont preset. Instead, the sampler uses the default preset, which is loaded during loadSoundFont(...preset:0). I have checked the soundfont and confirm that it contains the target preset on the correct bank.
I have also tried calling scheduleMIDIEvent to directly send a program change MIDI event. Unfortunately, neither of the method works.
I have included a working code here as a reference:
engine = AudioEngine()
sampler = AppleSampler()
sampler.loadSoundFont(sf2File, preset: presetID, bank: 0)

...

sampler.samplerUnit.sendProgramChange(preset, onChannel: 0)
//let event = MIDIEvent(programChange: preset, channel: 0)
//sampler.scheduleMIDIEvent(event: event)

sampler.play(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(pitch), velocity: velocity, channel: 0)


I have tried the following approaches:

When the preset changes, call:

sampler.loadSoundFont(sf2File, preset: presetID, bank: 0)


Load the SF2 file by creating multiple samplers and engines.

However, this might introduce higher memory overhead and potential performance issues.
Please recommend any helpful solutions.

Create multiple samplers, attach them to a Mixer and connect it to one Engine.
AppleSampler and the underlying AUSampler and AVAudioUnitSampler  share resources and memory, so multiple instances shouldn't be an issue. I could find the Apple documentation on it but following blog mentions sharing samples in memory (and also my own experience and measurements):
https://infinum.com/blog/getting-started-with-au-sampler/
